# Quantity adjustments for en_IN locale websites

Tags: quantity, zend-framework, regex

When adjusting quantity on the product page or cart page to any quantity, Zend Framework `isNumber()` function fails to validate the number for numbers passed through in an `en_IN` locale website. As a result, only a quantity of 1 is ever purchasable. It appears there is a difference in regex used to validate the number between `en_US` and `en_IN`.

Someone appears to have logged an issue with ZF however I cannot find any resolution/patch https://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-12256.

This may also affect other parts of the website which use `Zend_Filter_LocalizedToNormalized` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So `en_IN` does not actually come shipped with Magento and is a custom locale the team added in. Nevertheless, in order to get this to work, you'd require to "relax" the Zend Validation when validating the number (possibly via a rewrite) and make sure you protected and validate the input value.